# Page not found... yet! with Mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am using Mojilicious Lite.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
use strict;
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/' => 'index';

# Run the Mojolicious script in CGI mode.
app->start;

#template
__DATA__
@@ index.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        pass 15
    </body>
</html>
```

All is working fine but I have an **intermittent** issue,some times I get error page which says:

```
"Page not found... yet!
None of these routes could generate a response for your GET request for /, maybe you need to add a new one?"
```

**This happen very rarely (1 out of 20 hit)**.

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue and how can I overcome of it?

Thanks in advance..

**My Error Log is:**

```
[Tue May 26 18:12:42 2015] [debug] GET "/".
[Tue May 26 18:12:42 2015] [debug] Routing to a callback.
[Tue May 26 18:12:42 2015] [debug] Template "index.html.ep" not found.
[Tue May 26 18:12:42 2015] [debug] Template "not_found.development.html.ep" not found.
[Tue May 26 18:12:42 2015] [debug] Template "not_found.html.ep" not found.
[Tue May 26 18:12:42 2015] [debug] Rendering inline template "3e3201ab0667c1fc7f39089209f0435c".
[Tue May 26 18:12:42 2015] [debug] Rendering inline template "b2d451b47e2053ce583cbfdf7bcc6006".
```

Comment: `some code here` may be  your problem - if your route "stalls" then you might have this problem.

Comment: @Sobrique ..Thanks for your reply, can your please elaborate your comment?

Comment: That without your code, we have no idea. But if your code - for example - goes into an infinite loop, or stalls - occasionally - you might see a similar problem.

Comment: @Sobrique ..Please check my code ..I am having same issue with this code.Would you please help me.

Comment: Don't do this: `my $self = undef;` That'll screw up all sorts of things. Scope the `self` object locally.

Comment: @Sobrique   # Route to the main page
get '/' => sub
{
my $self = shift;
$self->render('index');

};  I have declared it locally but still it fails some time.

Comment: @Sobrique : can you please see my simplest code block which also gives the same error page and help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find that this is a bug with mojilicious light(while rendering **inline** templetes).
[bug report 1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mojolicious/7FDGtO-FV9k)
[bug report 2](http://irclog.perlgeek.de/mojo/2015-05-11)

---

I resolved my problem by using [external templates](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Tutorial#External-templates.)

Example:

My application file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
use strict;
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/' => 'index';

# Run the Mojolicious script in CGI mode.
app->start;
```

and my template file with name index.html.ep

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        pass 15
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** We have to define this file in **templates** directory .